# How to Display graph using onmouseover in datatabes

Tags: javascript, iframe, datatables

I have a table of data in datatables, i would like when the mouse is moved over a cell for a graph to display. The graph is created by a seperate php file and gets the event id passed to it.

My datatable is pretty standard i just cant figure out how to bring up an iframe in the datattabe redner function. Once you move the mouse away Id like the graph to disapper

I have tried iframes, modals and I cannot get this to work. Im assuming I need to use the render function to modify the code but whist my php isnt bad my javascript is poor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some code that you have tried would help a lot.

But here's an example using a bootstrap popover where you can hover over the first column and see a popover with custom html. 
This uses a trigger of Hover, so it will hide when you move the mouse away.

This uses the drawCallback event handler to register the bootstrap popover, rather than including it in the render function, however you can see an example of how the render function emits the html so if you have an iframe or custom code to use you can put it there.

http://jsfiddle.net/xab80ucj/8/

```
<table class="dataTable table table-striped" id="example"></table>

$(document).ready(function() {

  var dataSet = [
    ["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800"],
    ["Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750"],
    ["Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000"],
    ["Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060"]
  ];

  var myTable;

  myTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    data: dataSet,
    columns: [{
      title: "Name",
      render: function(cell, type, row) {
        return '<span class="show-modal" data-modal-id="' + row[3] + '">' + row[0] + '</span>';
      }
    }, {
      title: "Position"
    }, {
      title: "Office"
    }, {
      title: "Extn."
    }, {
      title: "Start date"
    }, {
      title: "Salary"
    }],
    drawCallback: function(settings) {
      $(".show-modal").each(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-modal-id');
        $(this).popover({
          content: function() {
            return '<h1>Your chart goes here</h1><p>The id passed in is <b>' + id + '</b> which is the extension in this example</p>';
          },
          trigger: 'hover',
          html: true,
          title: 'chart'
        })
      });
    }
  });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Updated the fiddle to include an example of linking to an external resource.

http://jsfiddle.net/khztLu9n/3/

In this example I changed the popover method to render an iframe. Note this also requires a little css to format the popover window using the id (new column added to data set)

```
.popover {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.popover-content{
      width: 480px;
      max-width: auto;
      height: 250;
  }


$(document).ready(function() {

  var dataSet = [
    ["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800", "FC65E5"],
    ["Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750", "FC65E5"],
    ["Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000", "FC65E5"],
  ];

  var columnDefs = [{
    title: "Name",
    render: function(cell, type, row) {
        return '<span class="show-modal" data-modal-id="' + row[6] + '">' + row[0] + '</span>';
    }
  }, {
    title: "Position"
  }, {
    title: "Office"
  }, {
    title: "Extn."
  }, {
    title: "Start date"
  }, {
    title: "Salary"
  }];

  var myTable;

  myTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    data: dataSet,
    columns: columnDefs,
      drawCallback: function(settings) {
        $(".show-modal").each(function() { 
          var id = $(this).attr('data-modal-id');
            $(this).popover({
            content: function() {
                return '<div style="width: 440px; height=220px"><iframe src="https://soccerscanner.net/pressure/showgraph.php?gameid=' + id + '" width=440 height=220></iframe></div>';
            },
            trigger: 'hover',
            html: true,
            title: 'chart'
          }
        )
        });
      }
  });


});
```

Comment: Hi Zeph, that works perfect but can I call an external file into the modal ?

I want to call this file
https://soccerscanner.net/pressure/showgraph.php?gameid=FC65E5

and have the graph displayed within the modal (or any other popup) but I need to pass the game id to get it to display the correct graph

Comment: Zeph, that s amazing ive struggled for days with this. Thank you so much